# Is there an equivalent R-package to 'rwolf' command in Stata?

Tags: r, hypothesis-test

I am looking for an equivalent R-package for 'rwolf' in Stata for multiple hypothesis correction. So far I have found boot_stepdown in the multitestr package which is based on Westfall & Young and should be equivalent to wyoung in Stata. However, I am looking for a procedure based on Romano-Wolf. Does anyone know a suitable R-package?

Thanks!!

Comment: Hi, I have written an [experimental package](https://github.com/s3alfisc/wildrwolf) that runs the romano wolf procedure based on results from the `fixest` package. In contrast to `rwolf`, it relies on the wild bootstrap, which speeds up the procedure, in particular when the standard errors are clustered into few groups. I hope to submit it to CRAN in the nearer future :)

Comment: Thank you very much - sounds great! I will certainly try it out.